# Problem upgrading Prisma version 4.10 to 5.2 in Win 11

Tags: node.js, node-modules, prisma

I want to use Prisma 5.2.0 over my old version 4.10. But when i run " npx prisma generate", i got an issue :
"Downloading Prisma engines for Node-API for windows [==========          ] 49%Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\ADMIN\Dfantasy\dFantasy-BE\node_modules@prisma\engines\schema-engine-windows.exe'".
By the way, i can't see my prisma version using prisma -v.

I'm using Node version 18 and Typescript version 4.7. In my package.json, all @prisma/client and prisma are at version 5.2.0.
In my schema.prisma, i set provider = "prisma-client-js"

Something wrong with my schema-engine-window.exe. How can i fix it ?

I tried to delete node_modules file and manually reinstalled @prisma/client and prisma but not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.